List of Examples of Mathematical Groups Appropriate for Kids
I would like to try introducing a small, diverse group of learners (ages 13 to 16) to some of the basic ideas of group theory, and ideas underpinning group theory: set, binary operation, closure, identity element, inverse element, associativity, commutativity, et cetera.
I'd like to have a list of lots examples of groups and almost-groups which are easily accessible to them, leaning on everyday things they are already familiar with but haven't thought of in the terms listed above.
Here are a few I can think of:

Mattress Flipping
Arithmetic of time
Symmetries of Triangle
Symmetries of Square
Symmetries of Rectangle (aka Mattress)
Permutations

Thanks for your time!

A very nice visual approach to basic results on cyclic groups is by using periodical curves such as Roulettes (Spirograph curves), Star Polygons, etc.

Just a friendly reminder that comments are meant to (a) ask clarifying questions, and (b) to suggest modifications to the question.  Comments which do not fall into one of those categories are likely to be deleted.  Answers can be posted in response to the linked duplicate question.
